# Nested vs flattened pattern match in Scala

Tags: scala, nested, pattern-matching, flatten

Let's say that I have *n* values in Scala named **v<sub>1</sub>**, **v<sub>2</sub>**, ..., **v<sub>i</sub>**, ..., **v<sub>n</sub>** of types **T<sub>ij</sub>** that are not necessarily different types for different *i*. I want to pattern match against the *n* values using a custom logic.

One way to do it is to nest all possibilities in case I need to be exhaustive (which for the sake of this example I need to be, otherwise I could use placeholder mag`_`c) and I can't merge branches (which for the sake of this example I can't as every custom logic is unique):

```
v1 match {
  case x1: T11 => v2 match {
    case x2: T21 => v3 match {
      ...
        case xn_1: Tn_11 => vn match {
          case xn: Tn1 => // Custom logic 1.
          case xn: Tn2 => // Custom logic 2.
          ...
          case xn: Tnk => // I am already laughing, but I have to write it down: 
                          // Custom logic k.
        }
        ...     
      ...
    }
    case x2: T22 => v3 match {
      // I guess you get the point. 
    }
    ...
  case x1: T12 => v2 match {
    // And so on until exhaustion in every meaning of the word.
  }
  ... // These three dots are needed here. Now I feel whole.      
}
```

The other option is to flatten the whole darn thing out:

```
(v1, v2, ..., vn) match {
    case (x1: T11, x2: T21, ... xn: Tn1) => // Custom logic 1.
    case (x1: T11, x2: T21, ... xn: Tn2) => // Custom logic 1.
    ...
    case (x1: T11, x2: T21, ... xn: Tnk) => // Custom logic k (with a hearthy chuckle).
    ... // Three dots saving my soul and my finger joints.
}
```

While the nested version avoids duplicate typing, it can lead to hard-to-read code due to indentation overflow when *n* is high (and we are not).

On the other hand, the flattened version contains a lot of duplicate code, but is easier to interpret.

Also, the nested version seems to be more performant as the checking of **x<sub>i</sub>** happens maximum once per type **T<sub>ij</sub>** (but perhaps I should not care about such things as the JVM could just optimize it all away, and I don't want to be [all evil](https://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil-donald-knuth-72-10-20.jpg)).

Which one is idiomatic Scala code and is therefore recommended? Is there a performance difference between the two versions?

Comment: From performance point of view nested version is better. Which one is better from readability point of view is depend on your personal preference, there is no definite answer.

Comment: @talex Doesn't a more performant nested pattern match invalidate the use of flattened ones for tuples, or perhaps in case of small n the difference is not noticable? In case of high n, the flattened version seems to be more readable as I don't have to recall (scroll back) which value is of what type, but I can see them at once, but I understand it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Only way to know how big is the difference is to profile. Theoretically nested work `O(n)` and flat is `O(e^n)`.

Comment: @talex Theoretically either could be faster or they could be the same speed, so you should not pick based on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick the option that most closely expresses the meaning of your code and not worry about performance. If the performance of this `match` is critical to your code then you have bigger problems with your design. (It is also not clear that one performs better than the other, so choosing based on assumed performance would be unwise).

If every `case` leads to an independent piece of code, then having a flat `match` is the most direct expression of the logic. Adding spurious nesting is just going to confuse things.

If there is some common code between two or more `case` expressions then they can be grouped into nested `match` statements so that the common code is not duplicated. This may also apply if there is some logical commonality between multiple cases that you want to expresses in the code.

Also note that you can chain partial functions using `orElse` which allows you to split one big `match` into separate functions with meaningful names, while avoiding nested `match` statements.